# SDMTools package has non-zero exits

Tags: r, sdmtools

I have been trying to install the SDMTools package from github, using devtools, and have also tried to install from the Cran archive, below is the code for installing through github:

```
devtools::install_github("jjvanderwal/SDMTools")
```

this is then the code to try and install from Cran archive:

```
install.packages("https://cran.r-project.org/src/contrib/Archive/SDMTools/SDMTools_1.1-221.2.tar.gz", repos = NULL, type="source")
```

Both of these produce the same error,

```
* installing *source* package 'SDMTools' ...
** package 'SDMTools' successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked
** using staged installation
** libs
Warning in system(cmd) : 'make' not found
ERROR: compilation failed for package 'SDMTools'
* removing 'C:/Users/micha/AppData/Local/R/win-library/4.2/SDMTools'
Warning in install.packages :
  installation of package ‘C:/Users/micha/AppData/Local/Temp/Rtmps1CvqJ/downloaded_packages/SDMTools_1.1-221.2.tar.gz’ had non-zero exit status
```

If anyone would be able to help with any suggestions of what to try or any alternative methods, would be greatly appreciated!

I am currently working on version 4.2.1, (have also tried this on version 4.1.3).

Comment: Same problem here. Have you been able to overcome the issue?

Comment: Not managed to find a solution yet, sorry.